# Hibernate throwing exception "Can't write to a readonly object"

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate , I am getting an exception

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at org.hibernate.cache.ReadOnlyCache.lock(ReadOnlyCache.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.action.CollectionAction.beforeExecutions(CollectionAction.java:110)

Although , I know that this happens when i have cache usage set to "read-only" but in my hibernate mapping I didn't specified cache. Moreover , I am using one-to-many relation which is "read-write". But , I really don't know why I am getting this exception.

**Mapping for BookingRecord Table**

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.acv.dao.tracking.BookingRecord" table="BOOKING" batch-size="10">

        <id name="id"
            column="ID"
            unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
        </id>

        <property name="userId" column="USER_ID" length="100"/>
        <property name="bookingEmail" column="BOOKING_EMAIL" length="100"/>
        <property name="bookingNumber" column="BOOKING_NUMBER" length="100"/>
        <property name="agencyId" column="AGENCY_ID" length="100"/>
        <property name="customerId" column="CUSTOMER_ID" length="100"/>
        <property name="sessionId" column="SESSION_ID" length="100"/>
        <property name="bookingChannel" column="BOOKING_CHANNEL" length="100"/>
        <property name="creationDate" column="CREATION_DATE" length="100"/>
        <property name="source" column="SOURCE" length="100"/>
        <property name="xmlResponse" column="XML_RESPONSE" type="text" />

        <set name="bookingServices" table="BOOKING_SERVICE" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key column="BOOKING_ID" on-delete="cascade"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.acv.dao.tracking.BookingServiceRecord"/>
        </set>        
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping for BookingServiceRecord Table**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class  name="com.acv.dao.tracking.BookingServiceRecord"
            table="BOOKING_SERVICE"
            lazy="false">

        <cache usage="read-write"/>

        <id name="id" column="ID" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">
                    <![CDATA[ACV_WEB.BOOKING_SERVICE_SEQ]]>
                </param>
            </generator>
        </id>       

        <property name="productCode" column="PRODUCT_CODE" />
        <property name="destinationCode" column="DESTINATION_CODE" />
        <property name="supplierCode" column="SUPPLIER_CODE" />
        <property name="serviceCode" column="SERVICE_CODE" />
        <property name="serviceTypeString" column="SERVICE_TYPE"/>
        <property name="price" column="PRICE" />
        <property name="taxes" column="TAXES" />
        <property name="serviceParentId" column="SERVICE_PARENT_ID" />
        <property name="serviceId" column="SERVICE_ID" />        
        <many-to-one name="booking" class="com.acv.dao.tracking.BookingRecord" column="BOOKING_ID"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am using Hibernate Template 
getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(bookingRecord); 
getHibernateTemplate().flush();

**It's thrown when I am Flushing through template**
Why it's so? What is the reason?

Comment: You don't have the BookingRecord object cache (cache usage tag missing). Is that missing or intentional (you want to cache only the collection)?

Comment: I think its intentional , but is that make any affect to cause an exception? Moreover , if I am not catching BookingRecord object it will bydefault "first-level-catch" which doesnt mean its "read-only" catch. Am I right

Comment: *catching spelled wrong "caching"

Comment: I would suggest to give it a try to troubleshoot this further. Mark BookingRecord as cacheable (read-write) and see if you get the same exception.